# How to access user data in MVC ASP.NET single user login setup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

After using the single user login option when creating my new MVC ASP.NET application, I can't seem to figure out how to access the user data within the default DB. I tried to connect to the generated DB by using:

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

then when accessing the DB I would use:

```
string username = db.ApplicationUsers.Where(x => x.Email == model.Email).Select(x => x.UserName).First();
```

with this code everything would compile fine, but I received an error saying:

> Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type 'IdentitySample.Models.ApplicationUser'.

If anyone has experience with using the single user login and knows how to fix my issues, that would be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you created a `DbSet<ApplicationUser>` in your `ApplicationDbContext`, `IdentityDbContext<T>` itself contains `Users` property, So you don't need to define it again.

Comment: After further inspection I think that was created after scaffolding a new controller and view. I reverted to a previous version before the scaffolding and the error is done. I'm not exactly sure what happened during the scaffolding process though.